# Let $E$ be a normed space such that $E \ne \{0\}$. Show that the discrete metric for the set $E \setminus \{0\}$ and $d(x,y)$ are equivalent

Tags: general-topology

> Let $E$ be a normed space such that $E \ne \{0\}$. Show that the discrete metric for the set $E \setminus \{0\}$ and $$d(x,y) = \begin{cases} |x|+|y|, x \ne y \\0 , x=y \end{cases}$$ are equivalent.

I've had trouble showing this for quite a while. I assume I have to rely on the continuity from discrete metric spaces to the real line here? Defining $id:(E, \rho) \to (E, d)$, where $\rho$ is the discrete metric and then showing continuity? I cannot seem to be able to formulate this. How can I start the proof?

Answer (score 1):

It is simply a matter of showing that both metrics generate the discrete topology. If $\delta$ is the discrete metric, you know that $B_\delta(x,1)=\{x\}$ for each $x\in E\setminus\{0\}$: each point of $E\setminus\{0\}$ is an isolated point. Show that for each $x\in E\setminus\{0\}$ there is an $r_x>0$ such that $B_d(x,r_x)=\{x\}$, thereby showing that $x$ is also an isolated point in the topology generated by $d$. There is a further hint in the spoiler box.

> You can define $r_x$ in terms of $|x|$.

Comment: Not sure how $d(x,y) = |x| +|y|$ generates the discrete topology. For example $B_d(x, 1)$ forms a square/diamond shape with the sidelengths being of length $1$. So it and contains much more points than just $\{x\}$?

Comment: @Simeon: That is not what the unit ball looks like, even in $\Bbb R^2\setminus\{\langle 0,0\rangle\}$ with the usual norm. If $x=\langle 1,1\rangle$ and $y=\langle 1+\epsilon,1+\epsilon\rangle$, for instance, then $|x|=\sqrt2$ and $|y|=\sqrt2(1+\epsilon)$, so $d(x,y)=\sqrt2(2+\epsilon)>2\sqrt2$ for all $\epsilon>0$.